# Time Duration In A Year In Go

Tags: go

I have made a function to check when the refresh token has expired. Within the function I also check if the refresh token has been more then a year.

```golang
// RefreshTokenExpired :nodoc:
func (s *Session) RefreshTokenExpired() bool {
    // if refresh token has been or more than a year since it was created.
    if s.RefreshTokenExpiredAt.UTC().Sub(s.CreatedAt) >= 365*24*time.Hour { <----
        return true
    }

    ...
}
```

Is there a better way to write this `365*24*time.Hour`?

Comment: I found new way, like this 
`if s.RefreshTokenExpiredAt.UTC().Sub(s.CreatedAt) >= timeNow.AddDate(1, 0, 0).UTC().Sub(timeNow)`

Comment: "better" here depends solely on your _definition_ of "year", whether its calendar year, solar year or 30758400 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to determine whether `s.RefreshTokenExpiredAt` is more than a year after `s.Created`:

```
 if s.RefreshTokenExpiredAt.After(s.CreatedAt.UTC().Add(1, 0, 0)) {
    return true
}
```